# Is it possible to update the TOC (TableOfContents) of a Word document generated with Syncfusion's DocIO lib?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

Our application generates a Word document using **[Syncfusion's DocIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/docio)** libs. Basically, we load a template and insert into it specific texts in specific bookmarks, generating a Word document that the user downloads on-the-fly.

**The issue we are facing is:**

- The template is 4 pages long and has  TOC.
- As we add content, the document size in pages increases (naturally)
- When the document is downloaded, the TOC still reflects the page  numbers used in the template. In other words, the user must manually update the TOC (secondary click ->    update field) in order to refresh the page numbers.

According Syncfusion's documentation (which is scarce...) this is not possible using their lib. So, we implemented an AutoOpen macro in the template that updates the TOC when the doc is opened as a workaround. However, this causes a security warning when opening the file (because of the macro), which makes our uses uncomfortable.

Does any of you have an idea to improve this implementation? 
Thanks,

Comment: I had same issue. Thank you for your question and answer. It helped me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
Document wordDocument;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(); 
wordDocument = word.Documents.Open(saveFileDialog.FileName);
wordDocument.TablesOfContents[1].Update();
wordDocument.Save();
word.Quit();
```