# How to add caption to image using wordml?

Tags: xslt, wordml

In my java application, I wanted to add cross-reference to an image but MS word allows it only through an image caption so I was trying to add a caption to an image with the help of wordML.

I can see that wordML allows user to add captions to a table but it doesn't seem to have such an option available for images. Can someone suggest something here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a Caption to a Table or Figure in OpenXml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548298/add-a-caption-to-a-table-or-figure-in-openxml)

Comment: not exactly, as in my question description itself i have mentioned we have ways to add captions to a table but i need to add caption for image and hence this is NOT duplicate, i believe.

Comment: what then, is your way to add captions to tables, programmatically speaking?