# How to set table caption with OpenXML?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to set caption to my table:

```
var caption = new TableCaption();
caption.Val = "Test";
table.Append(caption);
```

But nothing happens. Whats wrong here?

**UPADATE**

```
                foreach (var tabl in mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Table>())
                {
                    foreach (var trow in tabl.Elements<TableRow>())
                    {
                        foreach (var tcell in trow.Elements<TableCell>())
                        {
                            foreach (var para in tcell.Elements<Paragraph>())
                            {
                                foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                                {
                                    foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                                    {
                                        if (
                                            text.Text ==
                                                "my caption")
                                        {
                                            para.RemoveAllChildren();
                                            para.Remove();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Checkout the accepted answer for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548298/add-a-caption-to-a-table-or-figure-in-openxml) Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, I guess the `table` is a `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table`. This is not a valid parent for this element. The `TableCaption` should be added to a [`TableProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tableproperties%28v=office.14%29.aspx) element `<w:tblPr>`.

```
Table table = new Table();
TableProperties tableProperties = new TableProperties(
                  new TableCaption() { Val = "Test" }
                );
table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(tableProperties);
```

Then note the `<w:tblCaption>` element was added in the 2008 version of ECMA-376, so Word 2007 does not support this. The `TableCaption` class is only available since Office2010.

**To add/see this caption in word:**

> Right-Click on the table->Properties->Text/Replacement

Comment: I tried your code but its not help. In xml file i see:`<w:tblPr><w:tblCaption w:val="This is caption" /></w:tblPr>`. But when open document in Word2010 not see caption.

Comment: Particvaly i soled my problem. I can find a Caption and change it or delete. Example in question.

Comment: @KliverMax Hi, see updated answer. When I said *I confirm it doesn't work*, I was attempting to see the caption in the table in MS Word. But it is a *non visual* element. So after testing with Word 2010 I confirm the caption exists *Right-Click on the table->Properties->Text/Replacement*. From your updated code, it seems you want to access the column header of your table, that is not a *TableCaption*, but a *classic* content of `TableCell` inside a `TableRow`.