# Update Table of Contents that the Word Document has had Sections Changed by PHP on Server

Tags: php, vba, ms-word, rtf

A **RTF** document is edited on the server based off of user inputs on the web page. When the user hits the download button, it creates a word document with some of the sections deleted out of the **RTF** document.

Now that sections have been deleted, the **ToC** is incorrect. How do I update the **ToC** automatically when the word doc is opened ?

Macro doesn't seem to update the **ToC** automatically.

Php edits the rtf document using `str_replace()` 
and `file_put_contents()` Then it downloads it to the user on a website as a doc file

Just want the **ToC** to update automatically when the user opens the doc, so it doesn't have to be done manually.

Comment: Could you give us more information about this macro you mention, please? You can use the [edit] link below the question to add the information. What technology is used to create the Word document from the RTF?

Comment: Ideally it would be a macro that automatically creates or updates the ToC as soon as a use opens the document. That was php can do anything to the doc and the ToC will always be correct.

Comment: We couldn't get php to edit a word document with the file and string functions, so we made an rtf template, which worked. Then when a user wants to download it, it does header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$name.".doc"); which seems to convert it to word

Comment: A real DOC would not update its ToC, if I read this correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982624/is-it-possible-to-update-the-toc-tableofcontents-of-a-word-document-generated - so even if the RTF is converted to DOC somehow, it would not work as expected